# RMarkdown can Knit but cannot run: could not find function "read_csv"

Tags: r, r-markdown, tidyverse

This issue is really strange, I want to read a csv file and after getting rid of all unnecessary parts my entire code boils down to this two-liner:

```
library(tidyverse)
read_csv('data1.csv')
```

If I knit the Rmd file, it works and a new webpage opens as usual:
[image]

However, if I run it either by (1) clicking the green play button; or (2) clicking Run -> Run All button:

[image]

Then it just doesn't work (In case you are wondering whether or not there is a third line of code, I make the scope of the screenshot larger). The code is so short that I have no idea what could possibly be wrong.

Comment: did you run the entire chunk or just line 3?

Comment: Weird, assuming you also ran the line 2... what happens if you use `readr::read_csv('data1.csv')` in line 3?

Comment: read_csv is in library readr so try loading it first; library(readr). Also, try also with read.csv (it is on base R, library utils; do you have any special reason to prefer read_csv?)

Comment: @the-mad-statter I just revised the question, usually I click the green play button so I believe it is to run the entire chunk.

Comment: @user12728748 ah it works! Thanks! But do you have any idea why? Since I only imported tidyverse, I suppose there are no namespace conflict issues?

Comment: @Ventrilocus This won't work. My understanding is that tidyverse will load readr automatically so I cannot load it again. If I do so explicitly, I will be prompted the following: Show in New Window
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : Package ‘readr’ version 1.3.1 cannot be unloaded: Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘readr’ is imported by ‘tidyverse’ so cannot be unloaded

Comment: It seems you have some conflicts in your package installation. When you loaded tidyverse, readr appears as version 1.4.0. But when you attempt to load it manually, it states readr version 1.3.1 cannot be unloaded. Though you already have a solution, I would invest some time removing packages and re-installing. These conflicts tend to cause ramifications. It is already hard coding without having to deal with version conflict.

Comment: @Ventrilocus so what is the correct way of solving this? I remove readr and install it again?

Comment: Try running R in --vanilla mode, remove readr and install back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment from @user12728748, I changed

```
read_csv('data1.csv')
```

to

```
readr::read_csv('data1.csv')
```

and it works! But this is still odd since my understanding is that suppose there aren't namespace conflicts prepending namespace is not needed.

[image]

Loading readr explicitly, regardless of the order, does not work since it is loaded by tidyverse already:

[image]